# How to link configmap to external file?

Tags: kubernetes

With this we can create a configmap linked to external file.

```
kubectl create configmap database-config --from-file=database.properties
```

But when we edit the yaml, it will show that complete content of file is dumped there.

Is there anyway to just point to a file in yaml also so that I will keep the properties file in the same folder as the configmap yaml and appy the folder all the yamls with:

```
kubectl apply -f target_folder\
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

### What `configmap` is

> A ConfigMap is an API object used to store non-confidential data in
> key-value pairs. Pods can consume ConfigMaps as environment variables,
> command-line arguments, or as configuration files in a volume.
>
> A ConfigMap allows you to decouple environment-specific configuration
> from your container images, so that your applications are easily
> portable.

In other words when `configmap` is created from external file (like your case) or from other values, API server will validate if everything is correct and then will save it to `etcd`. This also explains reasons why when you `edit` your `configmap` you see its entire context. This happens because `configmap` is read from `etcd`, not any external sources.

This is also one of the reasons why it's not recommended to store save big files as configmaps or secrets - it will affect kubernetes cluster performance as all cluster's objects are stored within `etcd`.

### Kustomize

This is one of the way to achieve your requirement to run one command on creating/configuring `configmap` based on the file in the same directory.
It is a standalone tool to customize Kubernetes objects through a kustomization file.

I created a short and simple example to show the idea:

```
$ tree
.
├── application.properties
└── kustomization.yaml
0 directories, 2 files

$ cat kustomization.yaml 
generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true # this flag is used to avoid creation of new configmap, instead it will be modified when file context is changed
configMapGenerator:
- name: application-config
  files:
  - application.properties

$ cat application.properties 
listen.url=localhost:9010
client.url=some_url:3000
```

Test this, this command will **only render** configmap, it won't create it yet:

```
$ kubectl kustomize application.settings/
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application.properties: |
    listen.url=localhost:9010
    client.url=some_url:3000
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: application-config
```

Final step is to **apply** it:

```
$ kubectl apply -k application.settings/
configmap/application-config created

$ kubectl get cm
NAME                 DATA   AGE
application-config   1      23s
```

Short explanation to command above:

> To apply those Resources, run kubectl apply with --kustomize or -k
> flag.

### Useful links:

- [configmap - official kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)
- [Declarative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/)
- [etcd](https://etcd.io/)

Comment: Hello @uday. Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: I think what the OP means is to link the config map to an external file without using any command. He wants to apply the manifest file only. There hasn't seem to be a way so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912595/how-to-mount-the-properties-file-in-kubernetes-configmap-using-manifest-yaml